# match multiple variables to find "status", and populate in another tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tabs of data - 1 containing "Raw" data (blue screenshot), and an "Output" table (Yellow screenshot). I need a formula that will read the "Doc#", Active Revision, and Name from the yellow tab, go to the blue tab, compare all 3 entries, and then identify and populate the "status" in the yellow tab.

Each "Doc" has subsections (steps going up in increments of 10). So a user can have Doc 1, Rev E, step 10, 20, 30, 40 entries. For Error Proofing - I'll need to define higherarchey since the raw data is manually entered. For example - if a "User" is "Decertified" for any of the 4 steps but is "inactive" or "active" for other steps - they are decertified for the entire document.

Higherarchy is: Terminated>Decertified>Inactive>Active

[[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYNxy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYNxy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ih3Z.png)

I've tried Index/Match. It didn't give all the correct status - plus the data stopped processing after 19 rows and just gave "N/A" for rest of them (and became super laggy). I also tried Nested If/Vlookup but again it stopped processing after 6 cells and gave N/A for rest of the values, became super laggy, and didn't capture all the status options.

Comment: Hi Mayukh - this is great. There are some gaps, and I can fill those in - the doc# in the yellow is a dropdown for the other "doc#"s - so it'll get populated there - hopefully.  How do I extend the formula all the way to the end of the spreadsheet? if I understand correctly - this will only work for that 1 cell. I need it to populate all status all the way down.

Comment: also - how do i create a higherarchy?

- If "inactive" or "decertified" in any step, then for that document - all "steps" are considered decertified
- if "terminated" - than all docs and steps are "terminated"

Comment: Right - the "raw" data has Inactive, Active, Decertified, or Terminated status in M column above. I can see issues where for Doc 1, Step 10, 20, 30, 5, and 60 are "Active", 40 was updated to "Decertified" or "Inactive" (potential scenarios). I need that "User" status to be "decertified"/"Inactive".

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - See updated screenshot! Hopefully its more clear on the objective!

For Jim, I have revisions E with 3 different status's - Active, Inactive, and Decertified. I want it to find the "Decertified" and populate that one. 

For Joe, I have Active and Decertified - i want it to populate Decertified.